# How to know if the odometer in the car is fake or has been reset/reversed?

Tags: ford, escape, odometer

I am about to buy a car 2013 Ford Escape in Canada

The car is 10 years old but its odometer shows 48,000 KM = 30,000 Miles

does this sound right?

I am thinking that the odometer might have been changed/reversed/reset!

how to know when the odometer has been changed?

Answer (score 1):

30K miles for a 10 year old car is well below average.  But that doesn't necessarily mean the odometer has been changed.

See if you can locate any service records or other documentation that shows the mileage at different times in the past.  See if there are discrepancies.

What about the seller?  Is it a reputable business?  I'm sure that in Canada, as in the USA, modifying the odometer without disclosing that to a buyer is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

The 2013 Escapes can be changed diagnostically through OBD2 so there would not be any good visible ways to know. 30K is very low, I would be very skeptical.
Look around car for signs of wear and as jwh20 mentioned be sure to check for any documentation about the car.

Comment: A "typical" visual cue is to look at the rubber on the brake pedal ... how worn is it? If the rubber is worn a lot, it probably has a lot more mileage than what is shown on the odamomter.

Comment: Yea, Definently look around vehicle for wear and tear. I just meant no visible way to inspect the cluster to see if its been tampered with since this model is done  diagnostically. Many models you have to do it manually inside the cluster so your more likely to notice somethings there on those. Like slightly off needle, or finger prints/smudges on the inside background.

Comment: Other signs are tyre and brake pad wear. The European front-wheel drive models I use typically get through front tyres and pads in about 30,000 miles, and rear tyres and pads in 60,000. So if the car has supposedly done 30,000 miles, the front ones will either need changing, or recently been changed, and the rear part worn.